# on click Save page as pdf in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to save or capture the PDFs file in chrome extension is it possible ? I had used full screen capture but that is not working on PDFs files.i need to capture PDFs via Chrome extension is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If means use this extension for chrome "Capture Webpage Screenshot - FireShot" or "Web page captures from browser" extensions. you can get chrome extension from below links

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-page-captures-from-br/fomlbefjpamblimccfdomfgpgokdljcg?hl=en

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lightshot-screenshot-tool/mbniclmhobmnbdlbpiphghaielnnpgdp?hl=en

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/capture-webpage-screensho/mcbpblocgmgfnpjjppndjkmgjaogfceg?hl=en

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webpage-screenshot/ckibcdccnfeookdmbahgiakhnjcddpki/related?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Install a "doPdf" Printer application in your system and simply click Ctrl+p that particular page will go to print dialogue and select printer an "doPdf" It will save that page as pdf file.

Comment: thanks for you are response but i have to do with chrome extension because of i have to do some other functions.so i need to screen capture of the pdf via chrome extension